# Reading Excel file

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2008

What is a good way to read Excel files in C#? Point is having web page from which user can upload an Excel file, which will then be read and sent to database table.

OleDB way is useless here, as as far as I know, it can read use one file, and here would be many.

Best way I found so far is this one:

http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx

Any other better/newer methods?

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by the OleDB method can only read one file?

Comment: @M.Babcock It have connection string, and if I'm right, that should be path to file, and I need to have file uploaded, and then read. For many files.

Comment: Yes and you can build your connection string based on the file you want to open. What's the problem?

Comment: @M.Babcock, let's say I have uploaded files File1.xlsx, File2.xls, File3.xls, File4.xlsx, where I don't know how many files I will have, or how they will be named.

Comment: Under any circumstance you will at least need to know the *name* of the Excel file you want to open. There is no library that will be able to guess that for you.

Comment: @M.Babcock I intend to take filename from upload control, and then use it to locate file which I'll read after upload is finished.

Comment: What upload control are you using? Pretty much any of them will tell you the name of the file or files that were uploaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using OLEDB you can access multiple files by building your connection string based on the name of the file you want to open. Something like the following should work:

For XLSX:

```
var connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 12.0 Xml;HDR=YES\";", fileName);
```

For XLS:

```
var connString = String.Format("Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source={0};Extended Properties=\"Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1\";", fileName);
```

Where `fileName` identifies the file you want to open.

Answer (score 1):

The oledb provider will work, there are some gotchyas though.
There is a column limit if you aren't running the 64 bit version of the driver.
If you are running the 64 bit, you can't have any 32 bit office products on the system.

I would recommend setting in the registry 
HKLM\Software\Wow5432Node\Microsoft\Jet\4.0\Engines\Excel
Set the value TypeGuessRows equal to zero
This causes the driver to scan all rows to determine the type. The driver is a bit iffy in that if the first  say X number of rows in a column have numbers in it and then it has strings after, the type could be considered numeric, and anything containing a string will disappear and become null.
ex.

```
zipcode
--------
39934

18883

28472

52256-1252
```

the last row could be read as null because it thinks the first few are numbers, anything not fitting that format is converted to null.

So you CAN possibly  use oledb, just a few workaround to consider.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options

1. Using [Excel Interop](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel%28v=office.11%29.aspx), need excel intalled and you have to deal with COM
2. For XLSX files you can use [Open Office](http://www.openoffice.org/download/sdk/) SDK or third party libraries like [Epplus](http://epplus.codeplex.com/)

Answer (score 0):

I have recently had good success with Linq To Excel.  Depending on your exact requirements, that may be a good option

http://code.google.com/p/linqtoexcel/

Answer (score 0):

I've been using [Excel Data Reader](http://exceldatareader.codeplex.com/), which has worked extremely well. Admittedly it has been with a desk top application but it should work just as well in an ASP.net application.

Answer (score 0):

The open-source [NPOI library](http://npoi.codeplex.com/) provides pretty comprehensive functionality for reading and writing from Excel files (and other Office file formats), without needing to run Excel on the webserver (so it is much, much faster).

Note that it does not currently handle XLSX files.